# How to ignore pyc files in Netbeans project browser (regex question)

Tags: python, regex, netbeans

I want to ignore .pyc files in the Netbeans project browser.

I think I found a way: **TOOLS -> MISCELLANEOUS -> FILES** .

Here is a section called: Files ignored by the IDE .

The field there is waiting for a regex describing the file pattern . The default value for that field is:

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$
```

How do I modify this expression in order to (additionally) ignore the .pyc files ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this :

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn|.*\.pyc)$|~$|^\.(?!htaccess$).*$
```

I just added the `.*\.pyc` in the first group capture.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. (I've also realized now why regular expressions should be a topic known to every programmer :) )

Comment: @Andrei: That's why I have a t-shirt that reads `/bb|[^b]{2}/`. The number of people (even with a technical background) that have no idea what this could mean is astonishing.

Comment: This is actually in the interesting zone of not readily exposing you as a geek to the uninformed, while being one of the geekiest things around. ;-)